# Inserir imagem dentro de uma tabela existente em um documento do word

Tags: c#, microsoft-word

Tenho centenas de documentos e preciso adicionar um logotipo dentro de uma tabela existente. Estou usando o spire.doc, alguém tem uma luz pra me dar?

```
        Console.WriteLine("Digite o nome: ");
        String nome = Console.ReadLine();
        //Console.WriteLine("\nDigite o caminho do logo:");
        //String logo1 = Console.ReadLine();
        String logo1 = "C:\\ss";
        Section s = document.AddSection();
        Paragraph p = s.AddParagraph();

        Image image = Image.FromFile(@"" + logo1 + ".jpg");
        DocPicture picture1 = document.Sections[0].Paragraphs[0].AppendPicture(image); picture1.VerticalAlignment = ShapeVerticalAlignment.Top;
        picture1.HorizontalAlignment = ShapeHorizontalAlignment.Left;
        picture1.TextWrappingStyle = TextWrappingStyle.Square;

        Spire.Doc.Section section = document.AddSection();
        document.Replace("<nome>", nome, false, true);
        document.SaveToFile(@"C:\testes\Replace.doc", FileFormat.Doc);
        Console.WriteLine("\nArquivo criado com sucesso\n");
```

Comment: Já fez algum código começando? Poste pra gente ver. Está com alguma dúvida específica?

Comment: já fiz, editei a pergunta.... desculpe-me.